# Clicking a link in Excel to set autofilter on a different sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, hyperlink, filtering

Want to know how data filters as per criteria once I click on the link.

Dashboard sheet

[image]

Machining sheet

[image]

So here from the **Dashboard sheet**, once I click on the **view plan** (I2 cell) against **Panel saw 1** (F2 cell) I need the data of/under **Panel saw 1** (C3 cell) in the **Machining sheet** to be filtered automatically.
So as a newbie I don't know how to make this happen.